# Switching between activities when tab is selected using ActionBarsherlock tabs in android

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I am using tabs in  action bar using ActionBarsherlock library . How to switch  between activities when tab is selected .
My code is as below

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DetailFragment fragment =   (DetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);




        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
        {
            ImageView myMediaImg;   
            ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
            tab.setCustomView(R.layout.tab);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            if(i==1)
            {

                myMediaImg = (ImageView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.sk_abs__tab_icon);
                myMediaImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                tab.setTag("tab1");


            }   
            if(i==2)
            {
                myMediaImg = (ImageView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.sk_abs__tab_icon);
                myMediaImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                tab.setTag("tab2");

            }
            if(i==3)
            {
                myMediaImg = (ImageView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.sk_abs__tab_icon);
                myMediaImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                tab.setTag("tab3");

            }
            if(i==4)
            {
                myMediaImg = (ImageView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.sk_abs__tab_icon);
                myMediaImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                tab.setTag("tab4");

            }
            if(i==5)
            {
                myMediaImg = (ImageView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.sk_abs__tab_icon);
                myMediaImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                tab.setTag("tab5");

            }
            getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
        }





    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        if(tab.getTag().equals("tab1"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(tab.getTag().equals("tab2"))
        {
            Intent intent =new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(tab.getTag().equals("tab3"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity3.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(tab.getTag().equals("tab4"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity4.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if(tab.getTag().equals("tab5"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity5.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

When I run the application Activity1 repeatedly switching(got from logcat).

Answer (score 0):

According to what they say [here](https://groups.google.com/group/actionbarsherlock/browse_thread/thread/641762536860de8a/a1004be22dae45d9) this will not be possible to navigate between activities using tabs. :(
But if you found a solution please keep me updated.
thanks.